# Prevent line break in only one chapter title (chapter title run over margins)

Tags: line-breaking, margins, chapters, titles

One of my chapter titles is only one or two characters longer than the text width; therefore latex breaks the chapter title automatically and moves the last word to the next line.

How can I prevent the automatic line break in only one chapter title and allow the last word run over the margins one or two characters.

note: I want the title to be left aligned

Thanks

Comment: replace the last word `zzzzz` by `\rlap{zzzzz}` ? and use `\chapter[...]{...}` form so you only affect the main heading not table of contents etc

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and whether you load a package, such as `titlesec`, which affects the way chapter headers are typeset.

Comment: \rlap{...} solved my problem. thanks @DavidCarlisle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
\chapter[title with long text]{title with long \rlap{text}}
```

which hides the size of the last word (while not messing up the table of contents)